# sftp to webserver behind proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, sftp

I host a couple of websites on a webserver Centos 7 that is behind an ubuntu 20.04 proxy server (apache for http), as depicted in the figure below.

[image: Network setup]

Up until now there was no need to have sftp access to the webserver from internet, however for a new site, data files need to be uploaded every minute to the webserver. I cannot give direct sftp access to the webserver. So I would require the user to connect via sftp through the proxy.

I tried setting up sftp access to the proxy, and rsync the files to the webserver, but that requires a cron to run every minute, which causes some delay on data updates.

I looked at jump hosts as suggested, but this would require an ssl key pair from the proxy to the webserver. Which sort of defeats the purpose of having the proxy to secure the LAN servers.

What would be the best approach to upload files to the webserver over sftp through the proxy?

Thanks

Comment: Jump hosts won't work because that requires an ssl certificate from the proxy server to the webserver. Essentially creating an easy link to the LAN if the proxy is compromised. I would like to have no credentials of any form of a lan server on the proxy

Comment: Why would you need to have credentials on the proxy? The suggested answer should work for you too

Comment: yeah, with SSH, using a jump host or not, the credentials never leave the original computer. That's the point of public/private key authentication (also, you don't send *any* data, including user names, passwords, keys, … over an unencrypted link to a host you don't trust, so man-in-the-middling doesn't work)

Comment: I was under the impression that for jump host to work, a ssl key pair was needed for the connection between the proxy and the webserver. I did try jump host before, but did not succeed.   I probably do not fully understand how jump hosts work.

Comment: If you can get the *functionality* that you want (but not the timeliness) with cron,  look at inotify.